# I seem to have been given a 'Christmas present' on all my 9-vote answers ; is this legitimate?

Tags: discussion

I can't tell if someone is trying to be nice to me or if its something the site is doing, but someone upvoted all my 9-vote answers to 10. I probably wouldn't have noticed but there were a lot of my answers sitting on 9 votes -- 6 or 7 of them I think.

If it's something that was supposed to happen, well, I'm fine with that, but if someone's just upvoting a bunch of my posts to take them to 10, I believe that's not how the site is supposed to work.

While I like getting upvotes and badges as much as the next guy, I wanted to make sure the moderators know that this has happened to make sure it's not contravening the rules.

So is it legitimate?

Comment: Well, that was quick. From the reversal, it appears the answer is 'it was not legitimate'.

Comment: You have a secret admirer ;-).

Comment: Possibly he saw one good answer of yours, looked at other answers from interest (perhaps sorted by vote total), & voted them up as he read (& liked) them. I did a similar thing once - not realizing it was 'bad' & would get reverted.

Comment: @Scortchi Yes, I did the same thing myself before I found out (though I didn't think mine got reversed, so perhaps I didn't do it quite enough to trigger any response); it's likely to have been something relatively innocent like that, but I didn't want to leave it. It turns out I didn't need to worry - or to do anything - since it gets reversed automatically, presumably by a script that runs once a day.

Comment: @Glen: I find it a little annoying actually, as I think I've learnt more from CV by following people than by following tags; but I don't know what a better way to automatically look for & correct abuses would be.

Comment: @Scortchi I think I am in the same boat. There are particular users whose answers I especially seek out because of the insights offered by many of their answers. (I will use the tags when I am trying to find an answer a very specific question, but that's rare because usually it's either an issue I can research myself or it's a fairly hard question that I am not likely to find a good answer to.)

Comment: Something similar seems to be happening to me too, I'm getting 3-4 upvotes every morning. No reputation has been deduced, is this legitimate? Perhaps someone is hunting for voting badges...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the votes came from the same person within a given time period, our fraud detector will have picked it up and reversed the votes. We can all just carry on with our days - the system is doing its job!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the information.